# How to fill a reactive form using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, r, selenium, web-scraping

I need to fill the three fields of the form in [this page](https://www.metrocuadrado.com) in order to scrape the records of the resulting search, however, I haven´t figured out how to change the values to apartamento, compra usado and Medellín (Antioquia), respectively. Note that the first field is like a dropdown list with checkbox options and the third one is a text input, but you have to select one of the options displayed in order to get the correct results in the search. I'm using the Rselenium package in R but I think it might be easier using native javascript with RSelenium. I'm also open to suggestions in python or any other language.

```
script <- "
document.querySelector('[class = \"m2-select__single-value css-1uccc91-singleValue\"]').textContent='Compra usado';
document.querySelector('[name = \"businessType\"]').setAttribute('value', 'venta/usado');
document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0].setAttribute('value', 'Medellín (Antioquia)');
"

remDr$executeScript(script)


inmueble <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css', '#propertyTypes .css-1hwfws3')
inmueble$sendKeysToElement(list("Casas"))


ciudad <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', '.form-control')
ciudad$sendKeysToElement(list("Medellín (Antioquia)"))


buscar_boton <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', '#btnSearch')
buscar_boton$sendKeysToElement(list(key = 'enter'))
```

EDIT: Added the code I have so far, it changes the values in the html but when I click enter, it does the search with the default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use httr and make the same search request as the webpage does. You need to pick up an API key en route from one of the JavaScript files:

```
library(httr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

params <- list(
  "realEstateBusinessList" = "venta",
  "realEstateStatusList" = "usado",
  "locationsList" = "Medellín (Antioquia)",
  "realEstateTypeList" = "apartamento",
  "from" = "0",
  "size" = "50"
)

key <- httr::GET("https://www.metrocuadrado.com/results/_next/static/chunks/commons.3c50d9b2b91c3e061be4.js") %>%
  content(as = "text") %>%
  stringr::str_match(., '"X-Api-Key":"(.*?)"') %>%
  .[, 2]

headers <- c(
  "user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0",
  "accept" = "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  "x-api-key" = key
)


r <- httr::GET(url = "https://www.metrocuadrado.com/rest-search/search", httr::add_headers(.headers = headers), query = params) %>%
  content()

r$results
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! It does work for the most part. Doing exactly this only results in 7 records of the desired query, when in reality there over 9000. The problem is with the third input field where you specify the location, I tried several options and typing only Medellin works well since it displays the first 50 records of the ~9000 total. Do you know how I can continue doing this to obtain the info of the other results by moving through the pages (as of today, there are 193 pages of results)?

Comment: It was simply an iteration over the params list changing the "from" value. Sorry to ask again, but if you don't mind, could you walk me through how you got to this solution? or guide me to where I can learn how to? I understand the use of the httr package, but how did you find those urls and variables for the request? I want to replicate it with other websites.

Comment: Basically, I made those manual selections in the browser and used the network tab (F12 in browser)  to monitor the request the page made to retrieve the search results. I think I actually used FireFox in this case as Chrome was hanging. The params etc are listed within the network tab against the xhr request which returned the data.